# Netbeans extern connection

Tags: netbeans, remote-server

I'm trying to connect remote on a server, but when I want to test the connection I receive this error:

[image: error].

What can I do?

Comment: You can provide your current configuration so people may look at it. Without any information regarding what you have done so far we are not able to help in any significant way.

Comment: @atomman what exactly information you need about configuration?

Comment: I've just created a new remote connection..with hostname, port, user and password. When i've tested the connection i've got this error